# how to generate EDIFACT file with asp.net mvc 5 c#

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, converters, edi, edifact

I am working with a shipping domain application, and I need to convert some data  to EDIFACT format (client said "flight manifests to US customs. These will be sent in .txt UN/EDIFACT format"). Is it possible in c#? is there any third party tool available in market? what ever it is paid on open source. I actually have no idea about EDIFACT, just googled about it and found the full form of it and [this artical](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11278/EDIFACT-to-XML-to-Anything-You-Want?fid=206713&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26). EDIFACT To XML but didn't found anything for xml or json or anyting to EDIFACT. I found a pdf too [this one](http://www.gxs.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/tutorial_edifact.pdf) and got more stressed, its the old EDI standers since 1970. If you have any suggestion or related code, or any thing related to this, please share it, It may help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: if you want custom XML or JSON to XML, your best bet is to use a commercial universal translator.

Comment: no @Andrew I am just about to get my goal go through this: http://www.edidev.net/edidev-ca/help/Overview_GettingStarted/DotNetFrediSetup.htm#Setting%20up%20to%20use%20FREDI%20.NET%20Hybrid

Comment: See this video also if you need more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls_9e17l7rY

Comment: there is a free open source EDIFACT converter suite called "bots": http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml . Mappings are done in python, not c#.

Comment: I have seen this, but didn't suit as per my requirements. I didn't found any example for PAXLST and not any SEF file format. So I am going for http://www.edidev.com/ and EdiDev_Fredi. more over don't know python :(